# Stable norm on hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

For a hyperbolic surface $S$ and a homology class $h\in H_1(S)$ its stable norm is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}l(nh)$, where $l(nh)$ means the minimal length among all closed geodesics representing $nh$.

For a fixed simple closed curve $\gamma$ and its homology class $h=\left[\gamma\right]$ one can consider the stable norm of $h$ as a function on Teichmüller space, i.e. depending on the hyperbolic metric.

Has somebody attempted to express this function in terms of coordinates on Teichmüller space, say Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates or shearing coordinates?

Remark: If one would just minimize over the homotopy class of $\gamma$, then one would just be asking for the length of a closed geodesic and it should not be too hard to express this in terms of coordinates on Teichmüller space. The difficulty with the stable norm seems to be that one takes the minimum over the homology class, not just the homotopy class.